# combined insert sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have some tables, `users` (`uid int`) and `permission` (`pid, permi`) and `users_perm` (`id, uid, pid`)

permission

```
1, 's1'
2, 's2'
3, 's3'
```

users

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want for each user give him all permission

Comment: Please edit your question with any SQL you have written to attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean all users get all permissions the following should work:

```
INSERT INTO 
   [users_perm]
SELECT 
   [uid] = u.[uid]
   , [pid] = p.[pid]
FROM 
   [users] u
   , [permission] p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into users_perm
Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by u.uid), u.uid,p.id From users u cross join permission p
```